# Outlook Interop to perform server-side search with multiple filters

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, interop

I'm trying to use Outlook interop to retrieve all of the emails in my inbox from a specified sender email address and with a specified subject wildcard pattern and I am having trouble trying to apply two filters at once.

The first thing that I am concerned about is where the filtering takes place. Is it on the Exchange filter or on the client? Of course, for performance reasons, I would like the filtering to be done on the server. I see two methods “Restict” and “Find” that look like they are used for filtering and that they accept a SQL-like filtering string.

I’ve spent most of my time trying to get the Restrict method and have been unsuccessful trying to create a single filter with and “AND” clause that performs both Subject and sender filtering. I have been successful by applying two successive chained Restrict functions in a row as shown below but I suspect that the filtering is LINQ-like and performed on the client. Is this what is happening here? Shouldn’t I be able to combine the filter into a single compound SQL WHERE clause?

I’m wondering why the Subject filter seems to need to be prefixed by schema stuff and the sender filter seems to not accept the same schema stuff. Furthermore, note the two values assigned to senderEmailAddress (one of them is commented out). I’d like to filter using a standard SMPT address but only the Exchange-specific address seems to work. Any thoughts?

```
Application oApp = new Application();
NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
MAPIFolder inbox = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

subject = "%Challenge%";
//senderEmailAddress = "FirstName.LastName@company.com"; 
senderEmailAddress = "/O=COMPANYNAME/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=LANID";
string senderFilter = $"[SenderEmailAddress] = '{senderEmailAddress}'";
string subjectFilter = $"@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '{subject}'";            
var items = inbox.Items.Restrict(senderFilter).Restrict(subjectFilter);
```

The answer I am seeking would ideally include a way to be able to filter by *SMTP* email address and a Subject with a Wild card where the filtering is done on the server. (No server sided looping or LINQ-like methods that essential do the same thing with one statement.)

### Update 1

I did notice that I could filter using a "fromemail" property instead of senderemailAddress as shown above. The former seems to require the "schema" prefixing, the latter does not. Without knowing more, I assume that there are different approaches that have different syntaxes but the bad part is that the sender email address is not in a consistent format as described above.

> $" AND urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail LIKE '{fromEmail}'"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have the time to try it out myself but I hope this helps anyway. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._items.restrict?view=outlook-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Outlook__Items_Restrict_System_String_) it's possible to use a filter with logical operators AND, OR and NOT. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-query-keywords)'s an example of a DASL query with a logical operator:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & "(NOT(" _ 
& Chr(34) & "https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/" _ 
& "{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/Order%20Date" & Chr(34) _ 
& " IS NULL) AND " _ & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Company" 
& Chr(34) _ & " = 'Microsoft')"
```

The above query retrieves all contacts where the custom property Order Date is not null and the CompanyName property is exactly Microsoft.

If you've tried this already you could check the syntax again. It seems to me you need to be especially careful with the escape characters.